# Help parsing long (3.5mil lines) text file, line by line and storing data, need a strategy

Tags: design, php

This is a question about solving a particular problem I am struggling with, I am parsing a long list of text data, line by line for a business app in PHP (cron script on the CLI).  The file follows the format:

```
    HD: Some text here {text here too}

    DC: A description here
    DC: the description continues here
    DC: and it ends here.

    DT: 2012-08-01

    HD: Next header here {supplemental text}

    ... this repeats over and over for a few hundred megs
```

I have to read each line, parse out the HD: line and grab the text on this line.  I then compare this text against data stored in a database.  When a match is found, I want to then record the following DC: lines that succeed the matched HD:.

Pseudo code:

```
    while ( the_file_pointer_isnt_end_of_file) {
        line = getCurrentLineFromFile
        title = parseTitleFrom(line)
        matched = searchForMatchInDB(line)
        if ( matched ) {
            recordTheDCLines  // <- Best way to do this?
        }
    }
```

My problem is that because I am reading line by line, what is the best way to trigger the script to start saving DC lines, and then when they are finished save them to the database?

I have a vague idea, but have yet to properly implement it.  I would love to hear the communities ideas\suggestions!

Thank you.

Comment: With loading and saving line by line you will have massive overhead. I would read/write in chunks.

Comment: I see your point.  This is how I was told to do it, and so I have to implement it this way; however, thanks for the suggestion.  I may work it in for optimization!

Comment: sed/awk to read and parse then call your php script to check the database and update if needed.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Separate the problem -- one script plows through and reads and stuffs the interesting stuff into some sort of data store. Second script pulls from the data store and processes the records. I suspect this will be much faster than doing it in the same script for no other reason than the 2nd script effectively multi-threads the app.

Answer (score 2):

Write a two functions or a class `LineReader` with the following functions:

- string GetNextLine() : reads next line from file
- string PeekLine() : gets the next line from file, but don't move the file pointer

(you can implement this easily by a line buffer consisting of a string variable holding one line in advance; GetNextLine has to make use of that buffer as well as PeekLine).

Then, the implementation of `recordDCLines` should be something like

```
 while(substr(PeekLine(),0,3)=="DC:")
 {
    line=GetNextLine();
    // process line, append it to a buffer
 }
 // here, store the found DC block
```

EDIT: some pseudo code, I am not experienced in PHP, but I hope you get the general idea:

```
 void OpenFile()
 {
     // do stuff here to open file
     // ...
     $nextline = getNextLineFromFile();
     $endoffile = false;
 }

 string GetNextLine()
 {
      if(isset($nextline))
      {
         $result=$nextline;
         if(!noMoreLinesAvailable())
             $nextline = getNextLineFromFile();
         else
             unset($nextline);
      } 
      else 
      {
         $endoffile=true;
         $result ="";
      }
      return $result;
 }

 string PeekLine()
 {
     return $nextline;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  This is a wonderful suggestion, and I will investigate it more.  Could you explain this a bit more: (you can implement this easily by a line buffer consisting of a string variable holding one line in advance; GetNextLine has to make use of that buffer as well as PeekLine)?

Comment: @Jarrod; see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Implement a basic state machine.  As you are reading lines, note the last 'command' (dc, dt, etc).  When you get a 'HD', do your lookups.  When you are in a DC state, you know to accumulate the message until the next item isnt a DC entry, at which point you do a write.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider writing a [PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.php) in C or C++ for that purpose; you could then use low-level, but efficient syscalls (e.g. [mmap(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html), [read(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/read.2.html) into a large buffer, [readahead(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/readahead.2.html), etc...)

You could also delegate to a helper program written in C.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately this is delegated work and I have to implement it as I was told!